# Need help for simple plotting: mix of Correlation-Matrix and Heat-map function in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, heatmap

I have a data.frame or matrix that I want to turn in to a simple plot.
I tried heatmap and corrgram, but those are to complicated and are doing things (scaling etc.) that I don't want.

The matrix looks like this:

> ___V1_V2_V3_V4
>
> V1--NA--0---1----1
>
> V2---0--NA--4----2
>
> V3---1---4--NA---3
>
> V4---1---2---3---NA

So how often does V1 has something in common with V2, V3 and V4.
I just want the lower half of the diagonal triangle, and in the diagonal the variable names
AND since there are 5 values (0 till 4) I want 5 shades of red from light to dark red inside of the boxes.

Would I have to create that myself with rect(), and text(), but since my matrix is bigger than this example, I would like to loop over it instead of drawing every box by hand.
Could I do it with ggplot2?

Hope anyone has an idea!
ty

Answer (score 1):

Here solution using `ggplot2` and the data frame `dat` provided in @agstudy answer.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x,y,fill=z))+geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red",high="darkred")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that already looks really good. I don't know how I would rename the axis-1,2,3,4s etc with "text"? Can one use mtext(), or text() commands within the ggplot2 windows?

Comment: @OoTorstenOo If your data frame will contain x and y values as text that will be done automatically. Or you can use scale_x_continuous() and scale_y_continuous() to set breaks and labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can do present this as `levelplot.points` from the `latticeExtra` package.

[image]

First I recreate your data. my data is 3 columns x(1:4), y(1:4), and z the levels of your inputs matrix.

```
mm <- rbind(
  c(NA,0,1,1),
  c(0,NA,4,2),
  c(1,4,NA,3),
  c(1,2,3,NA))
dat <- expand.grid(x=1:ncol(mm),y=1:nrow(mm))
dat$z <- as.vector(mm)

library(latticeExtra)
levelplot(z~x*y,data=dat,
       panel=function(...)
       {
         panel.levelplot.points(...,cex=10,pch=22)
         panel.grid()
       },par.settings=ggplot2like())
```

Comment: so you create a 3-dimensional array with a 4x4 base and the z-values as my "intensity" values. I never used the expand.grid() or levelplot() function before so the code looks a bit bizarre to me :) is there a chance to minimize the grey area more? I really like the legend-scale on the right.

Comment: @OoTorstenOo yes. It is just a simple scatter plot with a special geom. This geom is filled or colored with the intensity matrix.